# Django Unit Test for downloading a file

Tags: python, django

Here are the items from the FileResponse object that was returned when I called the API to download the file (not requests library). I am using django test client. How do I download the Example file.json.

```
from django.test import Client
c = Client()

response = c.get(<URL>)
print(response.items())

('Content-Type', 'application/json')
('Content-Length', '2')
('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="Example File.json"')
('X-Frame-Options', 'DENY')
('Vary', 'Cookie')
('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff')
('Referrer-Policy', 'same-origin')
('Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy', 'same-origin')
```

The following two statements print empty list

```
print(response.getvalue()) # prints b'[]'
print(json.loads(b"".join(response.streaming_content))) # prints b'[]
```

I am trying to get to print the contents of the json file